# Making an "Opposite Inequality"

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I have the inequality $\ |i-j| > 1 $

I'm trying to build a piece wise function that is set to a different value $\ i,j$ values where this inequality is NOT true. Basically I'm trying to just flip the inequality logic.

However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to "Flip" this inequality into what I want it to be.

$
f =\begin{cases}
   & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      4 & \textrm{Insert Opposite Inequality Here}\\
      2 & |i-j| > 1
    \end{array}
\end{cases}
$

Thanks

Comment: If $a$ isn't "greater than" $b$, then what other cases are there?

Comment: The opposite of $>$ is $\le$.  That should be considered a basic fact.  There are three cases of which *exactly* one is true $a < b; a =b$ or $a>b$.  If $a < b$ is not true then either $a=b$ or $a >b$ and we use $a\ge b$ to indicate this..

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the direction of the inequality and allow equality: $|i-j|\le1$. However, as the absolute value function is non-negative, we may also write $0\le|i-j|\le1$.

Answer (score 0):

The 'opposite' of greater than is less than or equal to. So the 'opposite inequality' that you want here is $|i-j|\leq 1$.